# Availability of Azure container apps

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I am currently investigating if an architecture some colleagues designed will meet the customers' SLAs. One part of that architecture is the use of Azure container app. Azure states that the SLA of this service is 99.95%, but I am wondering if this can really be the case. I'd say it depends whether you enable zone-redundancy or not. If I am correct, what will be the availability of a container app distributed over 3 Zones in one region then? Can you please help me understanding this?

Also: What impact does it have to distribute over 2 Regions with 3 Zone each (with traffic manager at front)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the SLA of the Azure container apps is 99.95%.

[This link](https://aztoso.com/container-apps/deep-dive-operating-security-reliability-pricing/) states the SLA is independent of whether or not you use availability zones.  I couldn't find any further documentation that specifies that availability zone usage is required to get the full SLA.

The SLAs Azure provides give you a service credit if the uptime drops below the specified SLA, based on the following figures:

[image]

From The May 1, 2023 [Service Level Agreements (SLA) for Online Services](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/docs/view/Service-Level-Agreements-SLA-for-Online-Services?lang=1)